# Can Ionic be used for on desktop computers (as a web app)?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm very confused about this matter. Ionic just runs the application in a kind of web container if I'm not mistaken.

When I used the ionic serve command, I could also just use it in the browser of my desktop computer and it worked well. So why are there claims that it doesn't work on a desktop PC?

It's important that what I'm making right now also works for desktop PCs, that's why I'm asking.

It can be run from a web browser, that's fine for me (no need for electron to make it into a desktop app).

If it doesn't, is there a hybrid cross-platform framework similar to Ionic that also runs on desktops?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The claims you heard might be based on the fact that many [plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/) don't support the browser platform.

Comment: @Phonolog Would they work if electron is used? Because I saw that Ionic 2 is supposed to support electron; as well as I found [this template](https://github.com/eristoddle/Ionic2-electron-starter).

Comment: I don't know honestly. I'm not really into Electron and so I also don't know how Electron and Ionic play together.

Comment: I am currently using ionic to build a web app. The grid rewrite as well as the side menu component fits perfectly. Its just a matter of removing any mobile based dependencies. And because its a mobile framework the web app is perfectly fit for web app mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

As per the ionic [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/desktop-support/), the framework was initially intended for mobile, however, due to the widespread use of the framework for desktop based web applications, it does support the desktop to a certain extent with the help of native plug-ins whenever native components need to be leveraged.

However, if your need is to develop desktop applications using the web development technology stack (HTML, JS, CSS), it's best to look into technologies like [electron](https://electron.atom.io/), [react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) & [App.JS](http://appjs.com/). There are actually quite a few frameworks for achieving this but these are a few of my personal favourites.